# Java Could not Convert to TLS AWS EC2 Debian

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sockets, runtime-error, tls1.2

I have a Java Program that sends email using javamailx.
I have set all the following properties

```
    "mail.smtp.starttls.enable" : "true",
    "mail.smtp.auth" : "true",
    "mail.smtp.host" : "smtp.gmail.com",
    "mail.smtp.port" : "587",
    "mail.smtp.ssl.trust" : "smtp.gmail.com"
```

The error remains the same: Could not convert Socket to TLS.
I know there is a lot of topic similar, but none of them seem to solve my issue.
Please note that this works fine on my local windows and my raspberry pi, but it returns this error on my AWS EC2.

If someone can jump and help it would be really appreciated :D

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). The exact error and some more minimal code would be helpful.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.